# Prove using Jacobi's identity a commutation rule in SU(N)

Tags: group-theory

I've to use the following Jacobi's identity of $SU(N)$
\begin{equation*}
f_{aed} d_{bce} + f_{bed} d_{cae} + f_{ced} d_{abe}=0
\end{equation*}
to prove that holds true in every representation the following commutation rule
\begin{equation*}
[D_a, F_b] = i f_{abc} D_c 
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
D_a=\frac{2}{3} d_{abc} F_b F_c.
\end{equation*}
($F_a$ are group generators and $f_{abc}$ are the structure constants).

First of all I've simply replaced $D_a$ in the commutation rule and I've found
\begin{equation*}
[D_a, F_b]=i \frac{2}{3} d_{abc} f_{cbe} F_b F_e,
\end{equation*}
at this point I could play with indexes to find something interesting or using antisymmetry properties of structure constants, but I've no idea.